# Need Help regarding binding Issue

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, gridview, asprepeater

I have a repeater control inside a page and a gridview inside a repeater control. i want to bind the gridview. But i cant. My page is empty when i run it. and viewsource is also empty.
here is my code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="DataRepeater" runat="server" 
        onitemdatabound="DataRepeater_ItemDataBound">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:GridView ID="DataGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <%#Eval("FirstName") %>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="FirstNameTextbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>

protected void DataRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        DataCodeClass dc = new DataCodeClass();
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
        {
            GridView gvID = e.Item.FindControl("DataGridView") as GridView;
            dc.GetData(gvID);
            gvID.DataBind();
        }
    }
public void GetData(GridView gv)
    {
        var get_data = from a in dataContext.GetTable<PersonalDetailTable>() select a;
        gv.DataSource = get_data;
    }
```

Comment: Where is the repeater binding code?

Comment: i dont knoww, ive binded a gridview inside a repeater.

Comment: You must have some code somewhere which binds the repeater - if not then nothing will display, that is the correct behaviour. Why do you have a repeater to start with? What are you trying to do?

Comment: If you have a GridView inside a Repeater, then you probably have two level data source like list of students and for each student you have a list of grades. Is this the case?

Comment: i am just practicing to use a repeater control. nothing special.
just thought of binding the data in a gridview. 
your help will be very appreciable! :)

Comment: Are you trying to do as @AmiramKorach has suggested above? If not then you do not need a Repeater AND a GridView. Either remove the Repeater OR bind the data to the Repeater and remove the GridView and do what user1429080 has suggested below.

Comment: i understood each of your point.

Comment: what if i have two datasources and want to bind a grid and a repeater? so how am i gonna bind them?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Literal` control to show the FirstName, like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Literal ID="FirstNameLiteral" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>'></asp:Literal>
    </ItemTemplate>
    ....
</asp:TemplateField>
```